# TS 4.0 Variadic Tuples and Middleware pattern

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering how to use variadic tuples with middleware pattern because I didn't find any examples so far.
I have a function that composes middleware and looks like this:

```
const composeMiddleware = (...middlewares) => {
  if (middlewares.length === 1) {
    return middlewares[0];
  }

  return middlewares.reduceRight((f, next) => (...args) => next(f, ...args));
};
```

I'm using it like this:

```
composeMiddleware(
  (next, context) => next({ ...context, a: 1 }),
  (next, context) => next({ ...context, b: 2 }),
  ({ a, b }) => a + b,
)({}); // => 3
```

How would I type this function? It seems like variadic tuples should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nightmare, I think.  I'm not 100% sure which of the various approaches I can think of are closest to matching your use case.  You will likely need to manually specify or manually annotate types somewhere along the way; the compiler is not good at inferring the kind of higher-order generic function types implied by, for example, `(next, context) => next({ ...context, a: 1 })`.

---

If you're willing to give strong type annotations to your functions, like this:

```
const ret = composeMiddleware(
  (next: ((x: { a: number }) => number), context: {}) => next({ ...context, a: 1 }),
  (next: ((x: { a: number, b: number }) => number), context: { a: number }) => next({ ...context, b: 2 }),
  ({ a, b }: { a: number, b: number }) => a + b,
)({});
```

I can imagine having `composeMiddleware` typed strongly enough to verify/complain that this works and infer that the output of the `composeMiddleWare()` call is of type `(i: {}) => number`.  But it's ugly, using a lot of type juggling.

Since you're willing to consider the [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) feature coming to TS4.0, I'll use it, but I don't think it's necessary; it just makes it easier to access things like "the last element of the tuple".  Here's my attempt:

```
type Last<T extends readonly any[]> = T extends [...infer _, infer L] ? L : never;
type Ret<T> = T extends (...x: any) => infer R ? R : never;
type PLast<T> = T extends (...x: [...infer _, infer P]) => any ? P : never;
type AsChain<T extends readonly ((...x: any) => any)[]> =
  T extends [any, ...infer R] ? {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof R ? (n: (x: PLast<R[K]>) => Ret<Last<T>>, c: any) => Ret<Last<T>> :
    (c: any) => any
  } : never;
```

`Last` gives you the last element of a tuple. `Ret` gives you the return type of a function or `never` if it's not a function.  `PLast` gives you the last parameter of a function or `never` if it's not a function.  And finally, `AsChain<T>` takes a tuple of functions and tries to verify that it's a valid chain of function types for `composeMiddleWare()`.  Then, `composeMiddleWare()` is typed like this:

```
declare function composeMiddleware<T extends (readonly ((...x: any) => any)[])>(
  ...x: T & AsChain<T>): (i: PLast<T[0]>) => Ret<Last<T>>;
```

Here we are requiring that the tuple `T` of functions you pass in also matches `AsChain<T>`.  I'd love to be able to write `T extends AsChain<T>` but that's an invalid circular reference, so I have to use `...x: T & AsChain<T>` and deal with ugly error messages in the case where you've done something wrong.

If you try it with `ret` above, the compiler sees

```
/* const ret: number */
```

which is correct... yay!

If I give a bad function in there somewhere, say by taking that section function and typing `context` as `{oops: number}` instead of as `{a: number}`, then you get an error:

```
composeMiddleware(
  (next: ((x: { a: number }) => number), context: {}) => next({ ...context, a: 1 }),
  (next: ((x: { a: number, b: number }) => number), context: { oops: number }) => next({ ...context, b: 2 }),
  ({ a, b }: { a: number, b: number }) => a + b,
)({}); // error!
/* 
Type '(next: (x: {a: number;}) => number, context: {}) => number' is not 
  assignable to type '(n: (x: { oops: number; }) => number, c: any) => number'.
Types of parameters 'next' and 'n' are incompatible.
Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
Property 'oops' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' 
but required in type '{ oops: number; }'.(2345)
*/
```

It's an ugly error, but it's telling you that since the second function's context is `{oops: number}`, it was expecting the first function's `next()` callback to take an `{oops: number}` parameter, but it doesn't.  So, assuming you understand the error, the compiler is correctly telling you what's wrong with your call.  Yay again?  Maybe?

---

The other possible approach is where when you call `composeMiddleware` you have to specify it with a tuple of types like `composeMiddleware<[{}, {a: number}, {a: number, b: number}, number]>(...)` and the compiler will verify that the functions passed in act properly. But I've already spent a long time fighting with the first solution so I'm not inclined to go crazy with the second one.

---

I love playing around with TS's type system but my gut feeling is that the language isn't really ready for this kind of pattern, at least not in a way I'd be comfortable using in production-level code.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200623#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgZ2AHgCpQgD2BAdgEwSgCcI58B7XAGxCjlxAG0BdAPigF4p0scCiTAHQiAlrgBmEYlAD6AGijipMmCygB+WFABcUXBABu0gNwAoUJCgAlCClQduvbHkJQAFCKGY9DEAEouDmVpG00wvQNjYnNLaAAFeCQ0Rx4MFwEPLx8oYTFJUIUlApl4lkDODj9w+N19I1MLcGgAQQQAYQALOHE0dP43UnIqWg9PERy-CqrGf1ZHMyg0vldBP0UvEJlrdS0Ab0Wl3IBpYqgAawgQCgkeFj1TlczL69vrcPdcPXccxMQUaxMY7saY2OzIJL2NhsRQAY18syCYJQkJSHB0hyW7nh9ERlVxIEOAF86lFGmZ8BBYdQ4KQoBIAK64WHAURUKCwigAWzAFAQEAAsqJ8PhqBAAO60iB9J5udxDSg0OjucbeBEBJFTVj+NjuQ7ZPToABkUDaXR6uBS-m+oj0f2SqCYAAYQUjbCj-mjzGYzJzcEgSHYuBzubz+UKRWLJaQ9ViDNhvj89Ht6JEGVyAEahImg3DprPEfxwqg4BNQPY5pHx4DuFNeP2l4CKOB6ACMUBz8kOnz4iZyKZb+nz0kUGbTmezueHheLuEbydTQ4nMkr+Ortag9ZLfFHegATB2i92B6OOwvB3nl7ulwXD5qoABqKAZrv+Ws5kxQAD0X8DwCURCXgWPq+qGfKCsKooSlKsYeNWfbnuOt6rhwQHSEWIZzr25YofU2AbluWHYM2baHl2cbYSq-aLmhxDXrRd5rtOGENthKYUBQYAIEhk5VnwBEiKxxHPvuZHHvQp5EohN4jiJMkrqCcCPs+r7vv4n4-hgxDEBQxAAIRmF+ABUUBmKgzRQAA5D2ZZJuWF7TiYuG0bO844VOy6WQB+gUP+hyIAgogAOa4HAGZilAwAUJFFnWV8HjURxXE8TEjGodOcLqh5BaWUIZnNEQNxQGAtJwFydjSEQlnVl5DD4FZuC1XS4icjycCsuFEB5eZkCFbcJXEGVFXEFVmC1QQVljfQzXMqG7WiJ1eXxDpkDEKAVlJQgXmiEQXI7YFuBBWccRWQOKWfkSXlmBmDL-qQACODKiKQ9XiDFViWexnHcfJF25e4e4AMwACwAKz+GYRlfj6QA)